Не загружаются вместе Xdebug и phpmyadmin
Не загружаются вместе  Xdebug в vscode и phpmyadmin. То есть если  я запускаю xdebug, то не загружается phpmyadmin, если запускаю phpmyadmin то не работает xdebug. Как только я запускаю их вместе то нагрузка на сервер(OpenServer 6) возрастает вплоть до 100%. Если что то порт xdebug 9005.
